# Architectural Patterns for a Game

Tags: c#, vb.net, design-patterns, architecture

So I've got a solution that contains a few big projects, which I'm trying to break down into smaller projects with more isolated responsibilities. This is a game, but I'm mainly a LOB developer and I think the principles are probably universal, and I think I could learn something here.

The dependencies in some of the objects are a bit too tightly intertwined, and I'm hoping for some help on how to untangle them. Or maybe some sort of pattern or abstraction that might make them more manageable.

**Ares.Core.World** has classes in it like Creatures, Items, etc. All of them inherit from Entity, which is aware of what cell on the map it exist at. It accomplishes this by holding a reference to a  Ares.Core.UI.MapControls.MapCell... And you can see that the wires are already getting crossed.

**Ares.Core.UI.MapControls** contains Map and MapCell, each of which contain Lists of creatures and items that they contain. MapCell also inherits from Ares.Core.World.Entity since that solved a few early problems very elegantly -- for instance, all Entities have inventory.

I would like to find a way to split UI and World out into seperate projects (**Ares.World** and **Ares.UI**) since UI and the overarching world should probably be seperate concerns. But as you can see, the way it is now the two projects would need to reference each other, and circular references are not allowed.

I'm wondering if there are any architectural patterns out there that might help in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: You'll get a good response from this question on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It's nice to have everything derive from Entity, however it causes the degree of separation to blur to the point that there is no separation. I believe this is the first step. And I concur with @Rick

Comment: I usually solve circular references by creating a third project for entities (model) only and have all my entity classes that will be used in both World and UI projects declared there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your World classes - Creatures, Items, etc. - they all need *something* from MapCell.

Can you reasonably create an interface (or several) that represent what the World Entities need?  So that the Entities only need an implementation of that interface?

This would be the first step to decoupling the two.  Perhaps obviously, none of the method signatures or properties of this interface can include classes from the UI project.  It should be defined with standard types or custom types in a library both World and UI reference (e.g., Ares.Core).

Then, in the UI project define implementations of the interface(s) that encapsulate a MapCell and provide what is needed to the World Entities.

Use your IoC of choice to provide the implementation where it is needed, depending on how you get the MapCell, you may need to also layer on a Factory.

Without more details of your particular needs it's hard to be specific, but I think this approach in general should be workable.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually pretty helpful. So is this one of the reasons why the 'modern' style of programming ends up using interfaces for most everything? I can see how it would circumvent the problem of circular references.

Comment: @Brian: glad it was helpful.  I use this sort of pattern often to keep parts of systems independent, decoupled, and testable.  In addition to avoiding circular references, it also helps me focus on smaller individual chunks of functionality, and IoC just makes it easy to wire it all up and get the right implementations where they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with having classes in different namespaces interacting at a fine grained level. Separation of concerns can be done at the accessor protection level (public, protected, private, etc). You can break down your project into subprojects either logically or structurally, applying whatever extra organizational constraints you think are relevant.

Some strategies might be:

- Structurally separating logic, where each silo happens to reside in their own established namespaces, and interacting only through high level interfaces.
- Logical separation, where an assembly (or set of asms) become a logical project that may span multiple namespaces. Interaction could be done through interfaces, but also through thorough consideration of member access.

To untangle them, try to see the project from different perspectives. What can look like an utter mess from one POV can actually look elegant from another POV. If you find there actually is a reasonable logic behind their class structure, perhaps all that is needed is to start separating bits and pieces into different assemblies, with only minor tweaks to namespaces. If you find it truly is chaos, well, your work is cut out for you :-D

Answer (score 0):

1. Divide and Conquer  design suggest that you should separate UI and core component.
2. Your Game logic should be part of core module instead of UI.
3. UI should have graphical interface and action interface or object behavior interface and implemented by core module.

Comment: I've heard of divide and conquer algorithms, but not design. Is this the same thing as n-tier architecture?

Comment: the rule says that simplify complex module dividing small n simple component.

Comment: Oh ok that's the same thing I call single responsibility principle, SOLID, etc. Thanks :)